# How do I enable On Screen Keyboard in Active Directory In This Highly Restrictive Environment?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, windows-server-2012

## GOAL

Allow Users in "Students" group to execute `%WINDIR%/SYSTEM32/osk.exe`

---

## ERROR

```
This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.
```

---

## BACKGROUND

The domain configuration is highly restrictive. Although not perfect, the domain is meant to operate such that programs are enabled on a white-list basis only.

---

## Configuration

### Active Directory (AD) Configuration

- Student Policy

  - Computer Configuration
  - Policies

    - Windows Settings
    - ...
    - Security Settings

      - ...
      - Software Restriction Policies
      - ...
      - Additional Rules

        ```
        | Name                                   | Type         | Security Level | Description | Last Modified Date      |

        |----------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------|

        | %windir%\SYSTEM32\osk.exe              | Path         | Unrestricted   |             | 12/21/2017  10:11:58 AM |

        | %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\OskSupport.dll  Path | Unrestricted |                |             | 12/21/2017  10:13:13 AM |
        ```
    - ...
    - Application Control Policies

      - AppLocker
      - Executable Rules

        ```
         
        | Action | User             | Name                                  | Condition | Exceptions |
        | Deny   | EDUSRV0\Students | C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer | Path      |            |
        | Allow  | EDUSRV0\Students | %windir%\System32\osk.exe             | Path      |            |
        ```
    - ...
    - Administrative Templates: Policy Definitions (ADMX files) retrieved from the local computer.

```
TEXT TOO LONG FOR HERE AND EVEN PASTEBIN!
```

- User Configuration

  - Policies

    - ...
    - Windows Settings
    - Security Settings

      - Software Restriction Policies
      - Additional Rules

https://pastebin.com/raw/C4AciNXA

---

## Screen Caps

[image: Screen cap 1]

[image: Screen cap 2]

[image: Screen cap 3]

### [image: Screen cap 4]

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of restrictive policies configured. Sometimes it's not obvious which ones are producing the unwanted behavior.

To address this, create a separate OU that has copies of the involved GPOs, then begin removing or modifying policies until the unwanted behavior is eliminated.

Depending on how your GPOs have been built, you may be able to selectively disable them one at a time to quickly narrow down which contains the problematic settings.

Personally I like to disable *all* of the restrictive policies to prove to myself the problem is truly related to Group Policy, then add them back a few GPOs at a time until the problem returns.